# My plotly-dash app works perfectly in my local system but does not works in cyclic.sh

Tags: python, plotly-dash, webapp2, cyclic

I'm trying to host a Dash app on cyclic.sh but it's not working. It's stuck at Loading page, refer screenshot below:

[image]

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this.